# How to view cross domain Javascript requests in Firebug or any other plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain

How do I view cross-domain JS requests being made in a web page? Either thru Firebug or any other plugin?

For instance, suppose I visit stackoverflow.com, and they included a third party JS file (for instance, Google Analytics) How do I view the requests that are being made as the page is loading? the URLS being called, the parameters sent, the response, etc.

I can do this of course for AJAX requests made in the same domain rather trivially.

Comment: Just look at the Network tab.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either using the network tab in both

OR

- In chrome's console tab right click and select "Log XMLHttpRequest".
- In firefox's inspector "Log request and response bodies".
- In firefox firebug there is a little down arrow next to "console" in the tab, click that and ensure "Show XMLHttpRequests" is checked.

If there not showing up, they may be being loaded through JSONP calls and therefore are not actual XMLHttpRequests.  If that is the case, your best option is using the Network tabs.